# How to Load image on client browser stored on jboss server

Tags: jsp, jboss

i want to load image on client browser and images are stored on server drive D:\UserImages....

This is working fine on Eclipse ide but not able to see images on client side.

I used all possible ways but not able to view the image and its saying that "Sorry, could not load the image" after checking the tag using F12 button on browser.

Frond End:- jsp
Server:- jboss 4.0
Stored image Drive:-D:\UserImages on Server machine.

Comment: Show your code (html, jsp).

Comment: <TABLE border="0" >
                <TR>      
                   <TH>Hello <%=email %></TH>
                                                                                                                       ip- dynamic path of image         
                </TR>
               
               <TR>
 <TD><img id="img" src="E:/Software/workspace1/AG/WebContent/UserImages/<%=ip %>" height="200" width="200"/></TD>
                   
               </TR>
        
               <TR>
                   <TD> <button id="chg">Change Photo</button> </TD>
               </TR>
           </TABLE>

Comment: Edit the question, do not put the code into comment.